# ReplaceAll with defined replacement number Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a method for email masking. I need to replace letters in the email before `@` sign with stars. But the problem is that there is always should be exactly 5 stars and the first and last elements should not be hidden.
A sample input would be: `someemail@gmail.com`. Output: `s*****l@gmail.com`
So it does not matter how many characters between the first and the last one in the e-mail. Here is my code:

```
public static String maskEmail(String inputEmail){
    return inputEmail.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*");
}
```

My method masks this e-mail, but the problem is that I don't know how to put 5 stars exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be much simpler to just take the first letter and concatenate it with five asterisks and the substring starting from the letter before the `@`:

```
public static String maskEmail(String inputEmail) {
    return inputEmail.substring(0, 1) + 
           "*****" + 
           inputEmail.substring(inputEmail.indexOf('@') - 1);
}
```

Comment: Easier to read and more efficient than a regex-based solution. +1

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
inputEmail.replaceAll("(?<=^.).*(?=.@)", "*****")
```

Or this:

```
inputEmail.replaceAll("(.).*(.@)", "$1*****$2")
```

Note that this only works if there are at least 2 characters before the @.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static String StrToAsterisk(String email){
        if (email == null) return "";

        int flag = email.indexOf("@");
        if (flag < 0) return "";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(email.charAt(0));
        sb.append("*****");
        sb.append(email.substring(flag-1));
        return sb.toString();
     }

     public static void main(String []args){
         System.out.println(StrToAsterisk("someemail@gmail.com"));
         //input : someemail@gmail.com
         //output: s*****l@gmail.com
     }
 }
```

Comment: OP asked for 5 stars specifically.